# Vue.component do not shows the sub-component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I use `Vue.extend()` and `Vue.component()` create and register the component.

Here is my code:

```js
var app_nav = Vue.extend({
  template: '<div>app_nav</div>'
})

var app_sidebar = Vue.extend({
  template: '<div>sidebar</div>'
})

var app_content = Vue.extend({
  template: '<div>content</div>'
})

Vue.component('app-nav', app_nav)
Vue.component('app-sidebar', app_sidebar)
Vue.component('app-content', app_content)


var appView = Vue.extend({
  template: '<app-sidebar></app-sidebar><app-content></app-content>'
})

Vue.component('app-view', appView)

var div2 = new Vue({
  el: '#div2'
})
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="div2">
  <app-view></app-view>
</div>
```

But in my Chrome, it only shows the `<app-sidebar>` tag, why do not shows the `<app-content>`:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Every component must have exactly one root element

[Read in docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Templates). Add parent tag, I added `div` here as

```
template: '<div><app-sidebar></app-sidebar><app-content></app-content></div>'
```

```js
var app_nav = Vue.extend({
  template: '<div>app_nav</div>'
})

var app_sidebar = Vue.extend({
  template: '<div>sidebar</div>'
})

var app_content = Vue.extend({
  template: '<div>content</div>'
})

Vue.component('app-nav', app_nav)
Vue.component('app-sidebar', app_sidebar)
Vue.component('app-content', app_content)


var appView = Vue.extend({
  template: '<div><app-sidebar></app-sidebar><app-content></app-content></div>'
})

Vue.component('app-view', appView)

var div2 = new Vue({
  el:'#div2'
})
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="div2">
    <app-view></app-view>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. But wether there is a statement that say the `Vue.extend()` only can create a root tag like this?

Comment: @aircraft : [Please read this article](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Templates)